# Removing files and directories that already exist in other directories

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I need a help writing a script.
So basically I have directories named by current date, like
01-06-2014
02-06-2014
and so on
each of these directories has files and subdirectories inside.
But sometimes there are duplicates.
Like 01-06-2014 and 02-06-2014 may both have directory named d01 or file named f001.jpg, and so on

What I want to do is get rid of these same files and subdirectories, so that I don't use too much space (and besides, what's the point in having duplicates)

What is the easiest way to do it? Can someone help? please!

Answer (score 0):

For finding and removing duplicated files in specified directories consider using [fdupes](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes). There is no point in rolling your own script unless you want to learn something.